# Network drive connection failed. Which app/service to unlock in my firewall?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, network-drive

I installed TinyWall firewall and now Windows 10 cannot reconnect the network drives. Which service is responsible for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer form my own question, but I solved the problem: TinyWall has has an option call "Unblock LAN traffic". I missed it initially. It is not it the "settings" panel. It is in the right click menu (systray icon).

You are still welcome to answer the original question if you know the answer. I will not mark my answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

2022 now, this is for Networked drives, as the 'Unblock LAN traffic' didn't work in my case, and if you are running windows 10, try the 'Show Connections' and go right to the bottom of the list.
You should see a blue windows logo on the far left column, then scan right and see if the state says 'Time Wait' or 'Established'
Try unblocking the bottom 'Time Wait' and see if that solves your issue.
It worked in my case.

Notes:
I did try svchost, but there are so many you may not want to unblock all of them.
The method described above had an ipv6 address not an ipv4.
other bits
Did try the Learn mode, but it didn't help.
Also tried the Unblock LAN traffic, no go.
And tried all the Whitelist by options.
It is odd that the local LAN traffic didn't work, but you must remember that it may see IPV4 and IPV6 differently.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar issue in which I couldn't access a shared network location.
I did "Unblock LAN traffic" and enabled "File and printers sharing" but it didn't work.
What worked for me is to add the process "System" to the application exception list with "Unrestricted UDP and TCP traffic".